# How to set classpath for ojdbc14.jar in netbeans?

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, netbeans-8, ojdbc

Application is throwing exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Which I know is caused by `classpath` settings.

How to set it in netbeans 8?

Comment: Why are you using a Java 1.4 driver for Oracle?

Comment: `ojdbc14.jar` is completely outdated. Use an up-to-date driver that is intended for a current version of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans go to Project Properties Window then click Libraries in the left panel and in right panel there are 4 categories of classpath where you can configure:
1) Compile
2) Run
3) Compile Test
4) Run Test.  
To Add jar, Right click on Project folder in NetBeans,Then open Properties.Then choose Libraries. Here you can add jar.